# Javascript: Check if user do changes on Code Snippet

Tags: php, javascript

is there a javascript method to check if a user changes a given code?
Example:

```
<div id="mycodestyle">
<a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="image.gif"></a>
</div>
```

if the user now changes the code like

```
<div id="mycodestyle">
<img src="image.gif">
</div>
```

he get's a message -> Code modified. Extremetracking uses the same method, but I don´t know how they do it.
Here is the code of extremetracking

```
<div id="eXTReMe">
<a href="http://extremetracking.com/open?login=example">

<img src="http://t1.extreme-dm.com/i.gif" style="border: 0;"
height="38" width="41" id="EXim" alt="eXTReMe Tracker" /></a>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
EXref="";
top.document.referrer?EXref=top.document.referrer:EXref=document.referrer;
//--></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var EXlogin='example' // Login
var EXvsrv='s10' // VServer
EXs=screen;
EXw=EXs.width;
navigator.appName!="Netscape"?EXb=EXs.colorDepth:EXb=EXs.pixelDepth;
EXsrc="src";
navigator.javaEnabled()==1?EXjv="y":EXjv="n";
EXd=document;
EXw?"":EXw="na";
EXb?"":EXb="na";
EXref?EXref=EXref:EXref=EXd.referrer;
EXd.write("<img "+EXsrc+"=http://e1.extreme-dm.com",
"/"+EXvsrv+".g?login="+EXlogin+"&amp;",
"jv="+EXjv+"&amp;j=y&amp;srw="+EXw+"&amp;srb="+EXb+"&amp;",
"l="+escape(EXref)+" height=1 width=1>");
//--></script>
<noscript><div id="neXTReMe"><img height="1" width="1" alt=""
src="http://e1.extreme-dm.com/s10.g?login=example&amp;j=n&amp;jv=n" />
</div></noscript>

</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "changes a given code" ? By saving and modifying the document ? By using a debugger such as firebug ? By using a bookmarklet ?

Comment: the user can copy a script from my website and paste it on his own page. But if he do any changes on the script, he will get a error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, absolutely possible.

It is of course possible to watch your `DOM` and `HTML Markup` with Javascript. You could just have some sort of interval which checks for certain things or even use the `DOM Level 3 Mutation Events` like `DOMNodeRemoved` or `DOMSubtreeModified`.

The real question is, **is it worth anything** ? **NO**!

---

Any Clientside code could get modified or just removed the same way someone modifies your HTML markup. There is zero chance to have that kind of security on the client side only.
You would have to send your complete HTML code (or probably only parts of it) back to your server for any kind of validation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, for example by hashing the content of the page. However, this is a really bad idea. Any protection system you will add to your code can be just removed from the page, since the user has already the intent to modify it.

What you are trying to implement is some kind of software-protection system. These systems are worth their time when you distribute a binary, since disassembly and reverse-engineering are hard and take some time. However, we are talking about Javascript here, and reading/debugging Javascript is way easier. One could just cut out the part responsible for the protection.

However, if you insist, here is my solution :

- Using javascript, read the contents of the page you want to protect (i.e. using `InnerHTML`)
- Use a hash method like MD5
- Compare the hash with the one you have on the server using AJAX requests.